# pass a javascript variable into input text

Tags: javascript, input, primefaces

The following javascript code detects the users country via their IP:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript"> 
            document.getElementById("country").value(geoip_country_name());
 </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
  document.write(geoip_country_name());
</script>
```

In this second script I'm trying to get the name of the country and pass it to the input text corresponding to the country attribute:

```
<h:form id="newCustomerForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register Form</legend>
    <p:outputLabel  value="Country :" for="country"/>    
    <p:inputText id="country"
      value="#{customerMB.country}"
      title="Country"
      required="true"
      requiredMessage="The country field is required.">
  </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

**Update**

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
     <script language="JavaScript">  window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("country").value =geoip_country_name();
            };
     </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      document.write(geoip_country_name());
    </script>
```

But this is didn't work.  Any ideas on how to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for setting the value is incorrect. `value` is a property you assign, not a function you call, so it should be:

```
document.getElementById("country").value = geoip_country_name();
```

You either need to put this script after the `country` element, or run it in the `window.onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("country").value = geoip_country_name();
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/GLXc9/1/)

Comment: even with your code i couldn't get variable of the country into the inputText

Comment: Even if you put the script after the `country` element?

Comment: Please put back your original code, otherwise it looks like I'm just copying your question in my answer. If you want to post new code, add it at the end as an UPDATE.

Comment: It works for me too with html inputs but with primefaces inputText compounent no.

Comment: I don't know PrimeFaces. Can you show what the resulting HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to text box via paramaters / jquery

```
var input = $('#yourId');
var text = input.val();
input.val(text.substring(0, 1) + '.' + text.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you want to load the JavaScript before the 'country' element exists.

You have to **put the JavaScript part at the end of the HTML file** or execute this part in the document ready event, with jQuery you can use [$(document).ready(function...);](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)